# Passing matrix to a function. "invalid conversion from 'int (*)[columns]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]"

Tags: c++

Can't pass a matrix to a function, it seems to me that the problem has something to do with "columns", but I am not sure.
Keep in mind that I shouldn't use pointers or addresses.
If you have any comments about the quality of my code, please, tell me!
Here are all the errors: https://s12.postimg.org/5iuoci4bx/Untitled.png

```
    [#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stack>
void random_create(void);
int random_eval(const int, int, int);
using namespace std;
int main() {
    random_create();
    system("pause");
}

void random_create (void)
{
    const int Low = 0, High = 1000; unsigned int rows, columns;
    cout<<"Number of rows = "; cin>>rows;
    cout<<"Number of columns = "; cin>>columns;
    int a[rows][columns];
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    cout<<"Randomly generated matrix of size "<<rows<<":"<<columns;
    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
      cout<<endl;   
      for (int j = 0; j<columns; j++){
        a[i][j] = Low + rand() % (High - Low + 1);
        cout<<a[i][j]<<"   ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    }
  random_eval ( a, rows, columns);
}
int random_eval(const int array, int rows, int columns){
    std::stack<int> stackMin;
    std::stack<int> stackMax;
    stackMin.push(100000);
    stackMax.push(0);
 for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<columns; j++){
    if (array[i][j]> stackMax.top()){
        stackMax.pop();
        stackMax.push(array[i][j]);
     }
     else if (array[i][j]<stackMin.top()){
        stackMin.pop();
        stackMin.push(array[i][j]);
     }
 }
}
 cout<<"The biggest element in this array is "<<stackMax.top()<<endl;
 cout<<"The smallest element in this array is "<<stackMin.top()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Think you want to take a look at the code you posted. Lot of weird, not-compilable stuff in there.

Comment: You are right, something to do with te site. Fixe it

Comment: First, neither `int[N]` nor `int[N1][N2]` are `int`, nor can they be converted to `int`; it would be simplest to pass it with templates, as `template<size_t Rows, size_t Cols> int func(int (&arr)[Rows][Cols])`.  Second, in C++ programs, automatic storage C arrays must have their dimensions specified at compile time; `random_create()` would thus have to create a dynamic array using `new`, if you want to specify dimensions at runtime instead.  Perhaps look into `std::vector`, and/or make your own class?

Answer (score 0):

Your code mixes a lot of different things which makes it difficult to read the code. What you should do is make the functions do one thing only, and do what its name says. Instead of using raw arrays, use standard container instead. If there is some logic around that container, encapsulate it in a class. Here's what your code would look like if the suggestions were followed.

If you can't use pointers or addresses then you need to define a class to encapsulate the matrix:

```
class Matrix {
public:
  using Row = vector<int>; // or typedef vector<int> Row; if not using c++11
  Matrix(int width, int height) : matrix_(height, Row(width)) { }

  Row& operator[](size_t i) { return matrix_[i]; }

  using const_iterator = std::vector<Row>::const_iterator;
  using iterator = std::vector<Row>::iterator;

  const_iterator begin() const { return matrix_.begin(); }
  const_iterator end() const { return matrix_.end(); }
  iterator begin() { return matrix_.begin(); }
  iterator end() { return matrix_.end(); }

private:
  vector<Row> matrix_;
};
```

You have mixed the generating of matrix and printing it out, which is bad. Functions should not do more than one thing. Move the matrix printing into its own function:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Matrix::Row const& r)
{
   for (auto&& elem : r)
      out << elem << "   ";

   return out;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Matrix const& m)
{
   for (auto&& row : m)
      out << row << "\n";

   return out;
}
```

Change random_eval to take Matrix instead of three ints:

int random_eval(Matrix const& m) { ... }

Change random_create to produce Matrix instead of array, and don't lye to the reader - make the function do what its name says, that is create a random matrix and return it. The dimensions of the matrix to generate are taken as parameters. Also drop the C's rand and srand and use C++11 random generator instead:

```
Matrix random_create(uint32_t rows, uint32_t columns)
{
  random_device g;
  const int Low = 0, High = 1000;
  uniform_int_distribution<int> rng(Low, High);
  Matrix a(columns, rows);

  for (auto&& row : a)
    generate(row.begin(), row.end(), [&]() { return rng(g); });

  return a;
}

int main() {
    int rows, columns;
    cin >> rows >> columns;
    auto m = random_create(rows, columns);
    cout << "Randomly generated matrix of size "<<rows<<":"<<columns<<"\n";
    cout << m << "\n";
    random_eval(m);
}
```

You will need to include the following extra headers:

```
#include <algorithm> // generate
#include <random> // random_device, uniform_int_distribution
#include <vector> // vector
#include <cstdint> // uint32_t
```

Comment: Recommend returning that matrix. It's not doing much good living and dying in that one function.